# ScheduledExecutorService asynchronously run task till it succeeds if there are any exceptions

Tags: java, asynchronous

I am trying to use ScheduledExecutorService to implement a retry mechanism in java, that asynchronously retries a function after 30 seconds in case of failure, and retries up to maximum 3 times. I haven't used ScheduledExecutorService so would really like to get some inputs if there is a better way to write this. My goal is to retry and execute the function runMyChoreTillItSucceeds if there are any exceptions till it succeeds.

```
public void retryIfAnyExceptionTillItSucceeds(CustomerDO pmDO, MemberDO mbrDO) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);
    final int MAX_RETRY = 3;
    scheduler.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            try {
                runMyChoreTillItSucceeds(pmDO, mbrDO);
                scheduler.shutdown();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (counter.get() < MAX_RETRY) {
                    scheduler.schedule(this, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                else {
                    scheduler.shutdown();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks fine, there are a few improvements and considerations you might want to take into account:

1. I didn’t notice where you are incrementing counter, so instead of `counter.get() < MAX_RETRY` I've taken `counter.getAndIncrement() <= MAX_RETRY`. It will be first call of the method + 3 retry calls.
2. It may be worth thinking about a specific exception in which a retry is possible, but if you really need it for any exception, then you can leave a general `Exception` in the catch block
3. It's better to use `scheduler.shutdownNow()` instead of `scheduler.shutdown()` in the catch block to interrupt the thread immediately. This ensures that any pending tasks are canceled.
4. You might want to consider **cleaning up resources** associated with the retry operation, especially if `runMyChoreTillItSucceeds` holds any resources that need proper cleanup.

```
public static void retryIfAnyExceptionTillItSucceeds(PaymentDO pmDO, TransactionDO txnDO) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);
    final int MAX_RETRY = 3;

    scheduler.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                runMyChoreTillItSucceeds(pmDO, txnDO);
                scheduler.shutdownNow(); // Shutdownnow immediately on success
            } catch (SpecificRuntimeException e) { // catch specific exception to retry
                if (counter.getAndIncrement() <= MAX_RETRY) {
                    scheduler.schedule(this, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } else {
                    scheduler.shutdownNow(); // Shutdown if max retries reached
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Handle other exceptions if needed
                scheduler.shutdownNow();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @rickygrimes, if this answer was valuable and acceptable for you, pls accept it as answer